# Excel VBA error - Workbook does not respond when code runs with other macro-enabled workbooks open

Tags: vba, excel

#### Background

I have a dilemma. There is a workbook I have been working on for about a month. I have many named ranges, three queries, and several tables. One of the tables, (TABLE_Syteline_JobBills) is constructed from another table which is a query from a database. I refresh this other table (TABLE_Syteline_SingleLevel), 3 times, each time appending the data to the JobBills table.

#### The Problem

The code only works if no other Macro-Enabled Workbooks are open. If a Macro-Enabled Workbook is open, I get the error

> Runtime Error - Automation Error - The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

It occurs on the line:

```
.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert = True).Range = Row.Value
```

The code works without any error until a macro-enabled workbook is opened. A regular workbook does not cause the code to error. There will be no error when this is the only macro-enabled workbook open. Depending on which macro-enabled workbook you have open, the error might not happen until the third time through the nested for loop.

#### The Code

Here it is...the sub that causes the issue

```
'Option Explicit

Sub UpdatingTableJobBills()
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Programmer's Notes
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Copies three sets of data one at a time to one big table refreshing each time
'--------------------------------------
'Variable Declarations
'--------------------------------------
Dim JobNumber As String 'Variable Job Number
Dim RowCount As Integer 'Number of rows in table
Dim BOMSuffixes As Variant
Dim BOMSuffix As Variant
Dim Row As Range 'Used to loop through the different rows in the SingleLevel table we are going to insert into the JobBill table

'--------------------------------------
'Variable Definitions
'--------------------------------------
BOMSuffixes = Array("-conv", "-devices", "-electrical")
JobNumber = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cost Analysis").Range("JobNumber").Value 'job number - read from named cell

'--------------------------------------
'Delete any old data
'--------------------------------------
WipeOutBillData '---this function simply deletes 3 table databodyranges if they aren't empty already

'--------------------------------------
'Loop through each query and copy the query results to the JobBills table
'--------------------------------------
For Each BOMSuffix In BOMSuffixes
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM Query").Range("PartNumber").Value = JobNumber & BOMSuffix 'Changes part number to prepare for refresh
    ThisWorkbook.Connections("Syteline_Query_BOM").Refresh 'Refreshes specific connection to syteline
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Data").ListObjects("TABLE_Syteline_JobBills")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM Query").Range("TABLE_Syteline_SingleLevel")) <> 0 Then
            For Each Row In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM Query").ListObjects("TABLE_Syteline_SingleLevel").DataBodyRange.Rows
                .ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True).Range = Row.Value  '******** The row behind the trouble *********
            Next Row
        End If
    End With
Next BOMSuffix

Set Row = Nothing

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Data").ListObjects("TABLE_Syteline_JobBills")
    If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Data").Range("TABLE_Syteline_JobBills[Child]")) Then
        Call MsgBox("No data has been returned for job number: " & JobNumber, vbSystemModal, "No Data Returned")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    .DataBodyRange.Cells(2, .ListColumns("Extended Cost").index).Value = "=[Qty]*[Cost]" 'Redefines the value of column "Extended Cost"
End With
    

'--------------------------------------
'Sorts the table JobBills by descending Ext Cost
'--------------------------------------
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Data").ListObjects("TABLE_Syteline_JobBills"). _
    Sort.SortFields.Clear
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Data").ListObjects("TABLE_Syteline_JobBills"). _
    Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
"TABLE_Syteline_JobBills[[#All],[Extended Cost]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Data").ListObjects( _
    "TABLE_Syteline_JobBills").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

'--------------------------------------
'Deletes rows with an Extended Cost of Zero
'--------------------------------------

Dim Description As String
Dim RowMover As Integer
Dim ExtRowCounter As Integer

ExtRowCounter = 2

Do While Not IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Data").Cells(ExtRowCounter, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Data").ListObjects("TABLE_Syteline_JobBills").ListColumns("Extended Cost").index))
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Data").Cells(ExtRowCounter, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Data").ListObjects("TABLE_Syteline_JobBills").ListColumns("Extended Cost").index).Value = 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Data").Cells(ExtRowCounter, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Data").ListObjects("TABLE_Syteline_JobBills").ListColumns("Extended Cost").index).EntireRow.Delete
        ExtRowCounter = ExtRowCounter - 1
    End If
    ExtRowCounter = ExtRowCounter + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

If anyone can offer any possible explanation or solution to this error I am getting, it would be greatly appreciated. I just can't understand why the code wouldn't work with another macro-enabled workbook open. I made sure that I was specifically referencing "thisworkbook...". Perhaps there is a setting which I have selected within excel that causes the macro-enabled workbooks to work against each other.

Anyway - Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: Not that I can add to much to support this, but I have had a similar problem that I feel was caused by References in workbooks cause an issue, particularly when I have an old macro-enabled workbook compared to a newer macro-enabled workbook.  The code stopped running until I closed the old macro workbook (was working on updating the sub-routine into the new one).  The library references were different, which appeared to be the problem, otherwise the code was the same between the two, with different subroutine names.

Comment: Interesting...yeah in this case it happens with literally any macro-enabled workbook. I have hundreds of lines in this project, but a workbook with about 5 lines causes the project to stop responding and eventually it crashes.

Comment: Additionally, the error number is 2147417848

Comment: I'll take one more shot at this... For Each Row In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM Query").ListObjects("TABLE_Syteline_SingleLevel").DataBodyRange.Rows                        .ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True).Range = Row.Value  ... should anything be between .ListObjects().ListRows.Add()?  I'm not familiar with that function, but in some quick searching I see many examples as such.  If that doesn't help, sorry!  Good luck with this one.

Comment: Valiant effort Cyril. I still run into an error. Thank you for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

This part seems fishy to me:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Data").ListObjects("TABLE_Syteline_JobBills")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM Query").Range("TABLE_Syteline_SingleLevel")) <> 0 Then
            For Each Row In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM Query").ListObjects("TABLE_Syteline_SingleLevel").DataBodyRange.Rows
                .ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True).Range = Row.Value  '******** The row behind the trouble *********
            Next Row
        End If
    End With
```

Reduntant With block, try to use explicit object address? Same line, you access a Range object and assign a Range.Value to it.

Try:

```
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Data").ListObjects("TABLE_Syteline_JobBills") _
.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True).Range.Value = Row.Value
```

Another idea is to try using Workbooks("wbName") instead of ThisWorkbook to make sure the correct Workbook is processed.

Update:
Try commenting out `Set Row = Nothing`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I made that line change and still the problem persists only when another macro-enabled workbook is open. On the third time through the for loop (depending on which macro-enabled workbook is opened), the program stops responding and shuts down.

Comment: I am hesitant to replace thisworkbook with Workbooks("wbname") because I intend on saving this file with many different names in time.

Comment: Update: I tried replacing ThisWorkbook with Workbooks("wbname") , but to no avail. Still errored in the same spot :(

Comment: What happens if you comment out: `Set Row = Nothing` ? The error message seems like an object that's required has been deleted. Setting the Row object to Nothing could do that.

Comment: Just Tried it and it didnt really change anything with the way the code worked. It still produced the same error as before.

Comment: I tried copying all of the modules and vba code and saving that elsewhere. Then I saved the project as a .xlsx to eliminate all macros. After this deleted them all, I added back in the copied code. This still produced that same error. I have considered rebuilding the project from scratch but that would take at least 4+ days of work and the problem may still persist after. What a position to be in.